# replace the libc with compiled new library in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

currently I am working on ubuntu 18.04 with node.js version in 16.20. For some reasons, i need to upgrade the node.js version to 18.16 while still keeping existing ubuntu version.

By using nvm tools, the system switches to node 18.16, but can't use this version of node.js with error saying.

```
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

I checked my current version of libc is GLIBC_2.27, therefore upgrading the glibc-2.28 library with a few steps.

```
tar -xf glibc-2.28.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.28
mkdir build; cd build

../configure --prefix=/usr --disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-headers=/usr/include --with-binutils=/usr/bin 

make 
make install
```

finally in the build folder, i can see the compiled the library libc.so.6 and libc.so.

```
strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
.....
GLIBC_2.26
GLIBC_2.27
GLIBC_2.28
GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

so it works.

now I need to replace the library existed in path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, i tried the command

```
cp   lib.so.6  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

but it ain't work, any solutions

Comment: Replacing libc probably isn't a good idea. Try compiling node 18.16 with your existing libc instead.

Comment: Or use a package manager like Nix that can install a new node **and** a separate libc for that copy of node and its dependencies to use _without replacing or modifying any of your base distro's packages_. (Everything Nix installs goes into a hash-addressed location under `/nix/store`, and gets its dependencies only from other hash-addressed locations under that same prefix; because everything is hash-addressed, Nix can install multiple versions of the same package or library without getting them mixed up).

Comment: Docker is another option

Answer (score 1):

glibc is a complex set of libraries coupled with a dynamic loader, so replacing it is not a matter of simply copying libc.so to the right place.

Despite what many sources claim, it is possible to replace glibc with a newer version and keep the rest of the system mostly intact. **It is a delicate process and so it's usually a better idea to investigate other options first. Proceed at your own risk. This answer intends to demonstrate that this can be done, but it is not a complete step-by-step guide.**

For a smooth transition you need to ensure that during the `configure` step all important directories are configured the same as in the original OS-installed glibc. Some of these don't have a corresponding command-line option and need to be specified in a `configparms` file. Below is an example that I've used successfully on ubuntu 18.

```
mkdir glibc-2.28/build
cd glibc-2.28/build
echo "bindir = /usr/bin" > configparms
echo "sbindir = /sbin" >> configparms
echo "libdir = /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> configparms
echo "slibdir = /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> configparms
echo "sysconfdir = /etc" >> configparms
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.28
```

After building with `make`, the libraries need to be installed. To ensure that the `make install` step is not impacted by the libc change, we install to a temporary directory with:

```
make install DESTDIR=$(pwd)/../install
```

The next step will replace various libc libraries, but the old dynamic loader will still be in use. Following this, any dynamically linked executable will crash with Segmentation Fault on startup.

```
cp -var ../install/* /
```

To fix this, we have to switch to the new dynamic loader, by replacing the symlink at /lib64. Note that we have to invoke the new dynamic loader explicitly.

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so /bin/ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Finally, regenerate `ld.so.cache` with:

```
ldconfig
```

Notes:

- The process I'm describing aims at replacing only the libraries, keeping the whole build toolchain (if any) unchanged. This means that any binaries built on the system will target whatever version of glibc your gcc was targeting, not the new one.
- I've tested this procedure only within a docker environment. You may expect trouble when trying to replace the "live" libc while other processes are running.